# AEM OSGI bundle using docker container | Which forms add on package should I install?

Tags: docker, osgi, aem, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

As per our requirement we need to use AEM OSGI bundle configuration.
I am currently working on Apple Macbook.
To use FormsService and OutputService we installed "AEM-FORMS-6.4-OSX" package under "http://localhost:4502/crx/packageshare/index.html#"
(For windows we install "AEM-FORMS-6.4-WIN").
We have followed below installation steps:

1. Saved "AEM-quickstart.jar", "license.properties" files at one place.
2. Ran the jar file using the command "java -jar AEM-quickstart.jar"
3. Access http://localhost:4502/crx/packageshare/index.html#
4. Search for  "AEM-FORMS-6.4-OSX"
5. Download the package
6. Install the package
7. To reconfirm wether the package is successfully installed, you can go this path "./crx-quickstart/bedrock/svcnative/XMLFormService" and check if bin and META-INF folders are present.

Above steps are for AEM-OSGI configuration on macbook.

Now, I wanted to install this aem-quickstart jar inside a docker container

So steps I followed is:
1. Saved Dockerfile, "AEM-quickstart.jar", "license.properties" files at one place.
2. Ran the Dockerfile with command : "docker run -p 4502:4502 -t aem_quickstart"
3. Access http://localhost:4502/crx/packageshare/index.html# 
4. Search for  "AEM-FORMS-6.4-OSX"
5. Download the package
6. Install the package
7. Here, when I tried to traverse the path "./crx-quickstart/bedrock/svcnative/XMLFormService" I didnot find any bin folder.

Here my question is:
1. On which OS/platform does docker images run?
2. Which Forms Add on package should I install?
3. Because I am on mac OS I tried to install "AEM-FORMS-6.4-OSX" package but was unsuccessful. Also tried installed "AEM-FORMS-6.4-LX" but was unsuccessful.

Please help me here.. Let me know if any additional information is required

### FYI - Docker file has script as follows:

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

COPY AEM_6.4_Quickstart.jar AEM_6.4_Quickstart.jar

COPY license.properties license.properties

EXPOSE 4502

CMD java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024M -jar AEM_6.4_Quickstart.jar

---

Comment: Your docker image is running `alpine` which is probably not what you want for AEM. If you really want to do this you should use CentOS or Red Hat if possible. But personally (and from experience) I would advice you to NOT run AEM in a Docker container. If you want something "portable" use a VM which is preferably created with [Packer](https://www.packer.io). And for what it is worth you would need the Linux package (so neither Windows nor macOS).

Comment: Thank you Jens for your quick response! One point to add is we are not going to save any file objects (artworks, templates, fragments etc) in AEM docker memory. We just want to execute the OutputService, FormsService logic and retrieve the byteArray. Also if VM is an option, why not docker is a goto option?

Comment: The official word from Adobe is that neither Docker nor OpenJDK is a supported platform for AEM Forms 6.4.  Use at your own risk.  As Jens indicated, using it on a VM would be a safer choice.  See https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/deploying/using/technical-requirements.html for your available options.

Comment: Thanks for the URL @RobMcDougall. i went through the documentation, we are rethinking on what should be a feasible solution. I will post you on which path we chose.. thank you all once again